# Not Found ServerResponse code returned to android from ASP .Net MVC

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, multipartform-data

Recently I was working on a code to upload video to Server. It works fine when posting to php.

**PHP code which works fine with android:**

```
<?php   
   $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'; //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is neccessary and slash before 'uploads'

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
       echo "success".$file_path;
   } else{
       echo "fail";
   }

?>
```

**ASP .Net code which returns Not Found ServerResponse to android**

```
[HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
   {
       try
       {
           if (file.ContentLength > 0)
           {
               string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
               string _path = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Videos"), _FileName);
               file.SaveAs(_path);
           }
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success");
       }
       catch
       {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "failed");
       }
   }
```

**Android code for uploading Video**

```
    private int uploadVideo(String sourceFileUri) {
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + selectedVideoPath);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                videoURL.setText("Source File not exist :" + selectedVideoPath);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL("http://domain.online/api/User/FileUpload");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            final String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n" + serverResponseMessage;
                        videoURL.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(PostNewTarget.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n" + serverResponseMessage;
                        videoURL.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(PostNewTarget.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(PostNewTarget.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(PostNewTarget.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload f - s Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to receive video file on .Net?
Is this something to do with IIS?
What am I missing here

Comment: `ASP .Net code which returns Not Found ServerResponse to android`. Where is asp returning that? And where are you receiving that in your Android app?

Comment: That is what I asked. serverResponseMessage variable holds the 'Not Found' when serverResponseCode is not 200

Comment: Then what is it if it is not 200?

Comment: You are on!y writing to conn.getOutputStream(). But the server will return a page too if it is a normal server. You are not reading that answer. You should read all from conn.getInputStream().

Comment: I'm trying to upload video which is not uploading to server, it only respond with 'Not found' serverResponse.

Comment: No. The server responds with "success" or "failed". Now which of the two do you get? You do not get one as you do not read from the inputstream. You should do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. Actually we have to receive video file as a MultipartFileData within ASP .NET
Following is a the ASP .Net code for do that. And the CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider class helps to save video file name as it is.

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
[HttpPost]
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUpload()
   {
       // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
       if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
       {
           throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
       }

       // Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form
       // data will be loaded.
       string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
       CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
       List<string> files = new List<string>();

       try
       {
           // Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
           await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

           foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
           {
               files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
           }

           // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
       }
       catch (System.Exception e)
       {
           return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
       }
   }
}
   // We implement MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to override the filename of File which
   // will be stored on server, or else the default name will be of the format like Body-
   // Part_{GUID}. In the following implementation we simply get the FileName from
   // ContentDisposition Header of the Request Body.

public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider {
   public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }
   public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers) {
           return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
   }
}
```